# Prove if $a\in G$ is a fixed and $\alpha:G\to G$ is defined by $\alpha(x)=ax$ for each $x \in G$, then $\alpha$ is bijective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove if $a$ is a fixed element of a group $G$ and $\alpha:G\to G$ is defined by $\alpha (x)=ax$ for each $x \in G$, then $\alpha$ is one to one and onto

I was absent when this was taught. I know that for it to be one to one and onto that every element has to exist in G and that for each input, there could only be one output.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\beta(x)=a^{-1}x$. Then $\alpha\circ \beta$ and $\beta\circ \alpha$ are both the identity map.

Comment: Very elegant, +1

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $ax = ay$, then $x = a^{-1}ax = a^{-1}ay = y$. Also, for any $y \in G$, let $x := a^{-1}y$, then $ax = aa^{-1}y = y$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a(x_1)=a(x_2)$ then $ax_1=ax_2$

So $x_1=a^{-1}ax_1=a^{-1}ax_2=x_2$

Now for $y \in G$

Take $x=a^{-1}y$

So $a(x)=y$

This $a(x)$ is one ot one and onto.

Answer (score 2):

It is trivial. Let $x_{1},x_{2}\in G$. If $\alpha(x_{1})=\alpha(x_{2})$,
then $ax_{1}=ax_{2}\Rightarrow a^{-1}(ax_{1})=a^{-1}(ax_{2})\Rightarrow x_{1}=x_{2}$.
Therefore $\alpha$ is injective.

Let $y\in G$. Define $x=a^{-1}y\in G$,
then $\alpha(x)=a(a^{-1}y)=y$, so $\alpha$ is surjective.

Comment: Is there any mistake in my solution? Who down voted it?

Comment: No mistake. Probably because you called it trivial, OP obviously didn't thought it trivial :D Still, +1 from me